# ST_Contains(geometry A, geometry B) doesn't return polygons of B sharing external border with A

Tags: postgis

I have a large shapefile with 400k census sections in a table called `census_poly`. I want to return all the sections from `census_poly` contained in a district. Visually, the external border of districts matches perfectly with the borders of the census sections.

[image]

[image]

Still when I run this query

```
SELECT "census_poly".geom
   FROM "census_poly"
   JOIN "district_poly"
   ON ST_Contains("district_poly".geom, "census_poly".geom)
```

I get this

[image]

which excludes all the bordering census districts (FALSE NEGATIVE) such as these

[image]

I wonder why they are excluded and how to tweak my query to include them.

I could use the centroids of the census sections but that would not indicate whether a section is truly over two districts (TRUE NEGATIVE). Should I define a small buffer around my districts?

Comment: Your question and code do not agree. The title states "ST_Contains" but the SQL uses "ST_Covers".  You should look at the output of  `ST_Covers()`, `ST_Contains()`, and `ST_ContainsProperly()`.

Comment: @Vince Corrected.

Comment: The other question is whether the polygons have been processed to be mutually exclusive and exhaustively complete. There may be parts of the edge polygons outside the query geometry. You could try an ST_Difference to see if there are sliver remainders.

Comment: This is the correct behaviour for contains - the boundaries can not touch for contains to be true.

Comment: @IanTurton What function should I use?